# How to expose a dbus method with multiple arguments?

Tags: python, dbus

Is it possible to create a dbus method that accepts multiple arguments?

I wish to make a method like this:

```
def some_method(self, string, list_of_strings):
    #do something with arguments
```

into a method accessible using dbus. Is there a way to specify multiple arguments in dbus. My only solution so far is to use one big list as my arguments:

```
@dbus.service.method('org.my.service', in_signature='as')
def some_method(self, list_of_strings):
    string = list_of_strings.pop(0)
```

I would prefer to have the arguments separate - how, if at all, can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `in_signature='sas'` would achieve what you want.